# Sideload API Calls with PHP

Tags: php, json, database, api, storage

Is there a way to sideload (load multiple API calls at the same time) API calls to lessen the impact on API call limits, using PHP?

For example, we're using the [EchoNest API](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/index.html) to gather information on musicians. When the artist page on our site is accessed, we run multiple functions which each call a different API method that returns the specific data that we need. Everything works and looks awesome!

---

Here are a few (abbreviated) methods that we're calling that each count against our call limit:

```
function artistPageNews() {
    $artist_name = $_GET['artistname'];
    $results = iTunes::search($artist_name, array(
      'entity' => 'musicVideo'
    ))->results;

    $echonest_api_key = "OUR_API_KEY";

    // News Method
    $echonest_news = 'http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/news?api_key='.$echonest_api_key.'&name='.str_replace(" ", "+", $artist_name).'&format=json&results=2&start=0';
    $echonest_news_json = file_get_contents($echonest_news);
    $news_json = json_decode($echonest_news_json);
    $news_entry = $news_json->response->news;

    foreach ($news_entry as $news) {
        // Do Magic Stuff Here...
    }
}
```

---

```
function artistPageVideos() {
    $artist_name = $_GET['artistname'];
    $results = iTunes::search($artist_name, array(
      'entity' => 'musicVideo'
    ))->results;

    $echonest_api_key = "OUR_API_KEY";

    // Videos Method
    $echonest_videos = 'http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/video?api_key='.$echonest_api_key.'&name='.str_replace(" ", "+", $artist_name).'&format=json&results=6&start=0';
    $echonest_videos_json = file_get_contents($echonest_videos);
    $videos_json = json_decode($echonest_videos_json);
    $videos_entry = $videos_json->response->video;

    foreach ($videos_entry as $video) {
        // Do More Magic Stuff Here...
    }
}
```

---

We have maybe about 7 (or more) of these methods that are called on each Artist page load. Obviously this can mean trouble when lots of people are viewing the artist pages every hour.

I understand that there's a way to store the more static information into a database and use that info instead of calling the API methods on every request. I am currently exploring that option. But I also [read here](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/207086687-Sideloading-related-records) that there may be a way to 'sideload' the API calls so that you can make multiple requests at one time. In that example, they're using Curl. I'm trying to do this with **PHP**.

```
curl https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/fr/articles.json?include=users \
  -v -u {email_address}:{password}
```

Can anyone help me get started with this or perhaps recommend a better way to do this, such as storing this information into a database or table and pulling from that instead of calling the API every time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could make each request an ajax call so the main page can load the go off and query the API

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Even if I use ajax for each call, each method uses a different request url. Wouldn't that still require multiple calls and count against my limit?

Comment: yes it would. the only way to reduce the number of calls is to cache them locally

Comment: That's actually the way that I'm headed. Do you have a link or quick example on how to cache/store that data? Is this similar to what you mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325567/trying-to-put-api-data-in-database-with-php

Comment: very basically -- i would send all api requests to one script on your site, it would check a db table, if that request has been made before and is not to old, serve the data from the local db. If request new or data old, make remote API request save it in db and serve request. In the beginning most requests would go to the api, but slowly you build your own cache

Comment: Exactly. That's my thought process behind it. Thanks for clarifying. I will start with the example I posted in the above comment. And hopefully build something similar from that.